# Azure AD connect Health on ADFS WAP servers

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can you please suggest how to correct the connectivity issue on ADFS WAP 2016 servers to install AAD connect health agent

Here is the error :

---

Test-AzureADConnectHealthConnectivity : Azure AD Connect Health agent could not communicate to endpoint
https://policykeyservice.dc.ad.msft.net/clientregistrationmanager.svc using port 443. Please allow outbound
communication using port 443.
At line:1 char:1

- Test-AzureADConnectHealthConnectivity -Role adfs
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ConnectionError: (:) [Test-AzureADConnectHealthConnectivity], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to connect to the remote server,Microsoft.Identity.Health.Common.Clients.PowerSh
  ll.ConfigurationModule.TestAzureADConnectHealthConnectivity
  ```

Test-AzureADConnectHealthConnectivity's execution in details are as follows:
Starting Test-AzureADConnectHealthConnectivity ...

Connectivity Test Step 1 of 3: Testing dependent service endpoints begins ...
AAD CDN connectivity is skipped.
Connecting to endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com
Unhandled exception occurred: The operation has timed out
Connecting to endpoint https://login.windows.net
Unhandled exception occurred: The operation has timed out
Connecting to endpoint https://policykeyservice.dc.ad.msft.net/clientregistrationmanager.svc
Azure AD Connect Health agent could not communicate to endpoint https://policykeyservice.dc.ad.msft.net/clientregistr
onmanager.svc using port 443. Please allow outbound communication using port 443.
Unhandled exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets
cketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of tim
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.9.98:443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPA
ess& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Microsoft.Identity.Health.Common.Clients.PowerShell.ConfigurationModule.TestAzureADConnectHealthConnectivity.Te
ependentServiceEndpoints()
at Microsoft.Identity.Health.Common.Clients.PowerShell.ConfigurationModule.TestAzureADConnectHealthConnectivity.Pr
ssRecord()*****

---

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Clearly this is a connectivity issue between your box and azure. Follow the documentation here to make sure all the requirements are met: System.Net.Sockets cketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of tim or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.9.98:443

specifically,

> "If IE Enhanced Security is enabled, then the following websites must
> be allowed on the server that is going to have the agent installed.
>
> https://login.microsoftonline.com
> https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com https://login.windows.net
> https://aadcdn.msftauth.net The federation server for your
> organization trusted by Azure Active Directory. For example:
> https://sts.contoso.com"

if this does not fix it then you have something blocking some part of the network attempts to azure. you'll have to test it, figure out what it is and fix your network or machine firewall. easiest way is to open an IE browser and try to hit those endpoints by browsing to https://login.microsoftonline.com etcetc. they should all return something.

Comment: above URL are allowed In IE but no help .. Is there to see If the Firewall is blocking?

Comment: Will it be bi-directional ports which need to be opened from WAP servers. Also, what will be the destination in this case ? above URLs?

Comment: here are the network requirements: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-health-agent-install#requirements not bidirectional, only outbound for 443.